# MPJ Express eclipse - remove combination of letters

Tags: java, parallel-processing, mpi, mpj-express

I have to do an exercise for a parallel computing course. 
The task is using N parallel processes to remove all combinations of letters "RTY" from the string. 
Normally I'll do it with 
`String strAfter=str1.replaceAll("[RTY]","") ;`
But how to make it in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the String into N parts then make each process work on one chunk of String. The splitting mechanism should be intelligent enough to handle boundary values. You need to communicate one chunk of String to corresponding processes using *Send()* and *Recv()* methods for processing and in the end updated String should be communicated in same manner. Here you can find Javadocs http://mpj-express.org/docs/javadocs/index.html

Answer (score 2):

**Split, work, merge.**

1. Split in the main thread storing the output in a `Set`
2. Create N worker threads.
3. Have each worker thread `syncrhonized pick()` a string from the set at a given `index`, increase the index and process the entry
4. When `index` reaches `Set` size, glue everything back together. You may want to use `StringBuilder` and `append()` instead of concatenating Strings

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need to find a way to do this without using single-threaded functions on the entire string. What about breaking the string into N parts and letting each of your N parallel processes run the replace function on that part and concatenating the string after all the threads finished?